# Problem with accessible in DotNetOpenauth?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I working on MVC project and use DotNetOpenAuth to connect with twitter, Once i declare

```
private static InMemoryTokenManager _tokenManager = new InMemoryTokenManager("Twitter Consumer key", "Twitter Consumer secret");

    private InMemoryTokenManager TokenManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _tokenManager;
        }
    }
```

then when i build it got back an error which is

Error   1   'DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.InMemoryTokenManager' is inaccessible due to its protection level

How i set the accessible or do any setting to use it, Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InMemoryTokenManager` is for samples use only.  It's a *bad* implementation for a real app, which should be using its own `ITokenManager` class to store tokens in a database.  That's why its inaccessible to your web site.